# C++ optimization of function call batch mode

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, boost, containers

Edit: found a good solution(-25%) valarray, please leave a comment if i should change the question status in some way

Assuming I have an array or any other container with >E6 float/double values

and for every element inside the container i want to make a function call

eg. sin(x) or maybe something more complex.

code: C++11

the code is a benchmark example

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <valarray>
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"start\n";
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(-1000, 1000);
    int N=100;
    while(N--)
    {   
        std::cout<<"\nN: "<<N;
        {
            int T=1E7,T0=T;
            std::vector<float> array;
            while(T--)
            {
                array.push_back(dis(gen));
            }
            auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            while(T0--)
            {
                array[T0]=sin(array[T0]);
            }
            auto time2=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-start_time;
            std::cout<<"\nno: "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(time2).count();
        }
        {
            int T=1E7;
            std::vector<float> array;
            while(T--)
            {
                array.push_back(dis(gen));
            }
            auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            for_each (array.begin(), array.end(), sin);
            auto time2=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-start_time;
            std::cout<<"\nit: "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(time2).count();
        }
        {
            int T=1E7;
            std::valarray<float> array(T);
            while(T--)
            {
                array[T]=dis(gen);
            }
            auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            array=sin(array);
            auto time2=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-start_time;
            std::cout<<"\nvalarray: "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(time2).count();
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"\nfin\n";
    return 0;
}
```

is there a fast and good way to do it like this:

```
sin(&array)
```

or

```
array=sin(array)
```

Edit:

```
for_each(it) seems to be 5-10% slower;
no: 1014219
it: 1060500
valarray: 742929
in microsec;
```

Edit 2:
Sinus is a fairly complicated Algorithm, the question is more if someone knows a lib maybe in boost that has optimised some math functions to work directly with containers, instead of "booting" the hole thing everytime.

Comment: Based on the benchmarks, it makes believe that you're benchmarking unoptimized builds, as your `std::for_each` case essentially does nothing (and gcc even [eliminates the call to it](http://goo.gl/OZRE4f)), yet a time for that case still shows up on your benchmark. This seems like a perfect candidate for SIMD operations, but your chances of the compiler being able to generate SIMD instructions are likely significantly lower if you don't even bother with tuning the optimization switches.

Answer (score 1):

i feel there is no magic code to make it fast or good. just keep it as simple as possible.

i see two action you may take.
1) merge the two loop into one. you can use whatever loop you can use.
2) use parallel computing like OpenMP or thread in C++11.

one other thing is that if you can use uniform_int_distribution first, maybe you can use a hashmap to store the sin value if the T is really big.

Comment: the random in put is just so that the container has some values. i dont think its a good idea to have multiple threads working with one container at the same time

Comment: since you do not add/remove anything in the container, you should be ok to use parallel. oh, you changed your code.  in your case, the size is predefined, you can first reserve that size and change the value parallelly. or in your case, you can simply use array(use new, instead of array on stack)

Comment: also, you can try to avoid memory operation in the outsize loop by predefined the memory you need, memory operation is also a heavy and time consume in you case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use std::for_each to perform an operation on each element in a container like a vector.

This is fast.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/

Comment: i added for_each to the benchmark, seems to be slower

Answer (score 0):

If you're really only interested in `sin(float)` then AVX is the way to go. It can compute 8 32-bit `float`s in parallel.

Comment: Advanced Vector Extensions (AVX)? you mean building my function in assembler?

Comment: Using intrinsics would be fine for a simple task like this. But I'm not clear if `sin()` is your actual payload of interest, or just something you're using for demonstration purposes.